# What is the purpose of taking m = N + 1 when trying to prove that cauchy sequences are bounded?

Tags: real-analysis, real-numbers

As the title suggests, when we take two terms of the cauchy sequence corresponding to the n,m of the naturals, why do we have to make sure m = N + 1?

I am just including part of the proof:
Prove that any Cauchy sequence is bounded. What we know: we have a Cauchy sequence: ∀ > 0, ∃N s.t. ∀n, m > N, |sn − sm| < What we want to prove: this sequence is bounded: ∀n, |sn| < C Note: |sn| = |sn − sm + sm| ≤ |sn − sm| + |sm| by the Triangle Inequality Set = 1, because this sequence is Cauchy, ∃N such that ∀m, n > N, |sn − sm| < 1 Set m = N+1. Combined with our initial note, we can rewrite the following: |sn| < 1 + |sN+1| and this is true for ∀n > N This bounds all the terms beyond the Nth.

I would like to know the rationale behind this.
Thanks.

Comment: What proof then?

Comment: Can you please elaborate? I am really new to this topic and for a beginner like me, it will take some time to understand.

Comment: I am missing info that makes it possible to answer your question. That's all I am saying in my former comment, so there is nothing yet that can be elaborated.

Comment: Prove that any Cauchy sequence is bounded.
What we know: we have a Cauchy sequence:
∀ > 0, ∃N s.t. ∀n, m > N, |sn − sm| < 
What we want to prove: this sequence is bounded: ∀n, |sn| < C
Note: |sn| = |sn − sm + sm| ≤ |sn − sm| + |sm| by the Triangle Inequality
Set  = 1, because this sequence is Cauchy,
∃N such that ∀m, n > N, |sn − sm| < 1
Set m = N+1. Combined with our initial note, we can rewrite the following:
|sn| < 1 + |sN+1|
and this is true for ∀n > N
This bounds all the terms beyond the Nth.

Comment: That info should be added to your question by means of an [edit](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/3411134/edit). Be quick to copy so that you do not have to write it again.

Comment: [MathJax basic tutorial and quick reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Answer (score 1):

Let $(s_{k})_{k}$ be a Cauchy sequence.
As you point out, this implies the existence of an integer $N$ such that
$$
\forall m,n\in\mathbb{N}\colon m,n>N\implies\left|s_{n}\right|<1+\left|s_{m}\right|.
$$
Since $N+1>N$, you can deduce
$$
\forall n\in\mathbb{N}\colon n>N\implies\left|s_{n}\right|<1+\left|s_{N+1}\right|
$$
and hence
$$
\forall n\in\mathbb{N}\colon\left|s_{n}\right|<\max\left\{ \left|s_{1}\right|,\ldots,\left|s_{N}\right|,1+\left|s_{N+1}\right|\right\} .
$$
In particular, the right hand side of the above inequality is a constant.